# Cropping image height in responsive gallery

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, image

I've made my image gallery responsive with the following code:

```
<div class="line1">
<img src="image1.jpg" alt="image1.jpg" />
<img src="image2.jpg" alt="image2.jpg" />
<img src="image3.jpg" alt="image3.jpg" />
<img src="image4.jpg" alt="image4.jpg" />
</div>

<div class="line2">
<img src="image5.jpg" alt="image5.jpg" />
<img src="image6.jpg" alt="image6.jpg" />
<img src="image7.jpg" alt="image7.jpg" />
<img src="image8.jpg" alt="image8.jpg" />
</div>

.line1 { 
overflow:hidden; 
height:auto; 
}
.line1 img { 
width:25%; 
}
.line2 { 
overflow:hidden; 
height:auto; 
}
.line2 img { 
width:25%; 
}
```

I'm glad the responsiveness is working because it's exactly what I want. However, because the images are all different sizes, the outcome is this: http://i50.tinypic.com/2dm9yms.png and I would rather it be like this so that the images can be cropped: http://i46.tinypic.com/mm4xv6.png

What do I need to change in my CSS to get it like that?

Comment: Are you replicate this issue on http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: You can't crop an image using CSS

Comment: @TomSarduy But you can wrap it and make the parent have `overflow: hidden`

Comment: @JuanMendes: Yes, but that's a different question

Comment: @TomSarduy Why's that? It achieves the result the OP asked for.

Comment: @Yes, but `Hide != Crop` right? ;)

Comment: @TomSarduy If you can't see it on the screen, it's as good as cropped, you don't expect CSS to truly remove pixels from an image, do you? If that's the concern, you obviously need to regenerate the image

Comment: @JuanMendes: I see your point, I'm not good with English.  
**Emily:** That's minimally responsive, you can improve your gallery for devices using media queries: This is a good [Responsive Thumbnail Gallery tutorial](http://designshack.net/articles/css/how-to-build-a-responsive-thumbnail-gallery/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can give your div a fixed height, it would work. Also, you should not have classes `line1`  and `line2` It should just be `line`, notice you're duplicating your CSS

```
.line {
   height: 80px;
   overflow: hidden
}
```